# How to get title of current page with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

Good morning all,
I have a problem with WooComerce breadcrumbs. I want to add breadcrumbs bar with current page/product title on left side.  But i have no idea how can I get this title. I was able to add some custom text and move it to right with this code:

```
'wrap_before' => '<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb"><h1 id="name">Some text</h1>',
 'wrap_after'  => '</nav>',
```

Can you please suggest me some solution to get the title?

**EDIT:** Okey i manage to get some temporary results but its return only WooComerce pages name (shop,category names) it dont show product names. Any suggestions ?

Here is code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   /* <![CDATA[ */                      
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery("#name").append("<?php echo woocommerce_page_title();?>");
                                    });
                                    /* ]]> */
                                </script>
```

Comment: here is products api link: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/package-WooCommerce.Functions.Product.html and a link to get just the product title: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_template_single_title.html

Comment: Thank you for solution , tried some solution but cannot find good solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `woocommerce_get_breadcrumb` filter to modify the contents of the array that is sent to the template. You can take the page name from the end and put it onto the beginning, or add any other breadcrumbs you want. Each element is an array with the first element being the text and the second element is the link.

```
// filter the array that is sent to the breadcrumbs template
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', function( $crumbs ){
    // remove the last element (this is the page name by default)
    $page_crumb = array_pop( $crumbs );

    // add it back to the beginning of the array. 
    // you can change this to whatever you want, it's an array( 'Text', '/link' )
    array_unshift( $crumbs, $page_crumb );

    // return the modified array
    return $crumbs;
} );
```

Comment: Oh wasn't here for a while . Thank you so much for answer but there is one issue with this code . Element which is moved at the beginning of an array is raw text, its not a link and  i cant select it via css to move it to place where i want . Can i ask for explanation of this issue ?

Comment: You should be able to set the link with `$page_crumb[1] = $link_for_the_page;`

Comment: Ah thank you !  Well actually link is only minor issue but i would like to be abble to move this particular link on oposit site so i have effect like title on left and breadcrumbs on right  - Im not able to select this link right now . Is there some way to add class to this particular link ?

Comment: I don't think you can add classes, but the `array_unshift()` should move the page link to the left hand side...

Comment: Yes, it is moved to right hand side of course . But i would like to align it to right and make it bigger. We could say that i want to use this link as
`woocommerce-breadcrumb:before` . I tried to use Jquery for this but its unable to select this particular link